# Complemented subspaces of $c_0(\Gamma)$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite set. By $c_0(\Gamma)$ we denote the Banach space of all functions $f: \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, the set $\{ \gamma \in \Gamma : |f(\gamma)| \geq \varepsilon\}$ is finite, equipped with the norm
$$\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |f(\gamma)|.$$

In particular, $c_0 := c_0(\mathbb{N})$ is the space of real sequences that converge to zero.

It's known that every (closed) subspace of $c_0$ that is **isomorphic to** $c_0$ is also complemented in $c_0$. The proofs I know use Sobczyk's Theorem (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-02/S0002-9939-1971-0275122-0/S0002-9939-1971-0275122-0.pdf).

Is a similar result valid for uncountable $\Gamma$, namely: *Let $\Gamma$ be an uncountable cardinal. Is every subspace of $c_0(\Gamma)$ that is isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)$ complemented in $c_0(\Gamma)$?*

(note that Sobczyk's Theorem cannot be used in the uncountable (not-separable) case)

I suspect the answer is **no**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. See discussion in the end of the paper

[Sobczyk's theorem from A to B. F. C. Sanchez, J. M. F. Castillo, D. Yost](http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/21.pdf)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the reference. This helps immensely. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @ViníciusMorelli, [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137001/contractively-complemented-subspaces-of-c-0i) might interest you as well

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that as well! Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This also follows from Proposition 2.8 in

> S. A. Argyros, J. F. Castillo, A. S. Granero, M. Jimenéz, and J. P. Moreno, [Complementation and embeddings of $c_0(I)$ in Banach spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-london-mathematical-society/article/abs/complementation-and-embeddings-of-c0i-in-banach-spaces/BA5B5C978EBB68EF098CC822593D894D), *Proc. London Math. Soc.* **85** (2002), no. 3, 742–768.